# in R dividing datatables, mistake "arguments imply different number of rows"

Tags: r, datatable

I have 2 datatables, they are both of a same shape
hours1

```
hours1 <- data.table(structure(list(data = c("2022/05", "2022/06", "2022/07", "2022/08","2022/09"), `A` = c(105.480714285714, 90.0764285714286,48.7735714285714, 54.1864285714286, 86.5121428571429), `B` = c(98.69,37.69, 103.02, 56.74, 95.39), `C` = c(211.08, 231.15,256.56, 353.58, 131.1), `D` = c(23.02, 16.88,23.48, 29.9, 65.59), `E` = c(57.3, 34.6, 86.48, 89.19,44.57), `F` = c(194.36, 121.95, 154.82, 63.22, 101.09), `G` = c(81.35, 138.06, 93.1, 147.34, 124.3), `H` = c(248.69,191.3, 184.85, 105.63, 192.57), `I` = c(255.18,239.24, 288.42, 147.36, 242.56), `G` = c(76.66,105.3, 102.35, 131.21, 39.57), `K` = c(284.32,215.09, 181.23, 167.51, 145.38), `L` = c(68.78,100.39, 59.74, 54.09, 130.41), `M` = c(285.45, 180.34,132.47, 271.55, 262.32), `N` = c(0, 0, 0, 0,57.56), `0` = c(1990.36071428571, 1702.06642857143,1715.29357142857, 1671.50642857143, 1718.92214285714)), row.names = c(NA,-5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fbc0f00f2e0>))
```

mydata8

```
mydata8 <- structure(list(data = c("2022/05", "2022/06", "2022/07", "2022/08","2022/09"), `A` = c(167, 159, 88, 152, 176), `B` = c(167,104, 106, 120, 120), `C` = c(111, 131, 168, 184,100), `D` = c(167, 104, 144, 184, 172), `E` = c(167,71, 104, 152, 96), `F` = c(167, 159, 168, 104, 136), `G` = c(95, 159, 104, 184, 176), `H` = c(167,159, 168, 108, 176), `I` = c(167, 159, 168, 108,176), `G` = c(136, 159, 168, 184, 72), `K` = c(167,159, 128, 108, 140), `L` = c(167, 159, 104, 104,176), `M` = c(167, 132, 88, 184, 176), `N` = c(0,0, 0, 0, 176), `O` = c(2012, 1814, 1706, 1876,2068)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.table")
```

first I run the code

```
hours1[is.na(hours1)] = 0
```

then
I transform both sets to data table format

```
setDT (hours1)
```

setDT (mydata8)

I have also made field data of a same format

```
hours1 %>% modify_if(is.POSIXt, as.Date)

format(hours1$data, "%Y-%m-%d") 
hours1$data <- format(as.Date(hours1$data), "%Y/%m")
```

then I need to divide one datatable by another and I run

```
Workload_full_avtime <- data.frame( data=hours1$data, hours1[,-1] / mydata8[,-1])
```

And I get the error message:

```
Error in data.frame(data = hours1$data, hours1[, -1]/mydata8[,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 5
```

But both samples have the same number of rows... what can cause the problem, and how to overcome it?

Comment: can you `dput(head(hours1))` and `dput(head(mydata8))` please?  People cannot use screenshots of data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I am sorry, I have not understood how to use the functions...

Answer (score 0):

The `data.table()` call is expecting name/value pairs.

Try:

```
Workload_full_avtime <- cbind(hours1$data, hours1[,-1] / mydata8[,-1])
```

this binds the "date" column to a data frame created by dividing the non-date columns, resulting in a data frame of the required shape and content if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Thank you Paul, yes, cbind worked, but at the same time in the Workload_full_avtime  i have dissapeared column date

Comment: typo by me sorry, I wrote `hours1$date` but it should be `hours1$data`